# Symfony 2 many to one

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am learning symfony 2. In documentation I saw example many to one relations. I tried do it in my code. I have two entities: products and categories.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category",inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $category;
```

In entity Product I have such code. I executed `app\console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` and `app\console doctrine:schema:update --force`. The table Category has appeard, but in table products I don't have field category_id. I cleared cache but it doesn't work. What is wrong?

**Product**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;

/**
 * Product
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param integer $price
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

**Category**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Category
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**UPD2** after php app\console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

```
 c:\xampp1\htdocs\first_project
# php app\console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
CREATE TABLE category (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NUL
L, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE =
InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE product (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
, price INT NOT NULL, description LONGTEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CH
ARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;

COMP323 c:\xampp1\htdocs\first_project
#
```

Comment: Try to remove manually the cache/dev and cache/prod ?

Comment: What's the command return ? Are you sure to refresh your database ?

Comment: command return nothing to update,yes, I have refreshed

Comment: Drop the `inversedBy` from the `ManyToOne` as you suggest this is jsut a `OneToMany` relationship (not `OneToMany`). Does that help?

Comment: Is Category in targetEntity the fully qualified class name? You need to set it to the full namespace classpath. For Example: targetEntity="SomeBundle\Entity\Category"

Comment: Share your `Products` entity too, this could be an issue with case or namespaces or ...

Comment: u don't need JoinColumn these values will be set by default

Comment: It's good idea, but I have taken this example from official docs.

Comment: Does `Category` entity have `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")`?

Comment: I think you need ManyToMany relation

Comment: Yes, Category have this code

Comment: You have `$products` as an `ArrayCollection` in the `__construct` function? Could you post both entities as there's a lot of questions going back/forth :)

Comment: I know maybe it isn't good code, but I read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata and took it from this page

Comment: The code looks good to me. Try dropping all tables and running `app\console doctrine:schema:update --force` again so that's it's creating tables from your entities and not updating existing ones.

Comment: I did, but no, it didn't helped

Comment: `Category` is at least missing `@ORM\Entity` and `@ORM\Id`.

Comment: `Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.`

Comment: I corrected it, but it didn't helped. I created this class http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: Please delete both tables in your database and add the output of `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to your question. Also check what version of symfony you're using. With sf3 the console command changed to `bin/console`.

Comment: As @Yoshi mentioned -- annotation in the `Category` entity needs to be corrected for making it working.

Comment: Try running `doctrine:schema:validate` to make sure your mapping files are valid. This should tell you if there are any wrong / missing annotations.

Comment: It returned mapping -OK, database -OK

Comment: @Vadim.K you should update the entities in your question just so we know that you fixed what everybody here suggested, especially Yoshi, and also for future readers.

Comment: A crazy idea, could it be that you're not actually using [annotation mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html) but rather [YAML Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html) or any other form of the available [mapping types](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html#mapping-objects-onto-a-database)?

Comment: maybe when I was installing symfony I choised yaml, bun I don't remember. How can I check it?

Comment: Have a look in the `app/Resource` or `src/YourBundle/Resource` folder. Maybe there you'll find some schema files (yml or yaml).

Comment: Yes, In folder `Resources` there are `category.orm.yml` and `product.orm.yml`

Comment: There you go, that's why the annotations don't have any effect. You'll need to decide which you want to use in the future. I'd opt for annotations.

Comment: ok, How I change yml to the annotations?

Comment: Check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html#mapping-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in the annotation with the complete namespace reference to the Category entity.

```
/**
   *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category",inversedBy="products")
   *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

These two worked for me in symfony 2.8 (lts).

Update your DB with `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql`

I have removed the getters and setters which you can generate with:

- `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Product`
- `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Category`

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;

/**
 * Product
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;
```

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Category
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

The above code will generate the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE category (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE product (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, category_id INT DEFAULT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, price NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL, description LONGTEXT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_D34A04AD12469DE2 (category_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE product ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D34A04AD12469DE2 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id);
```

Comment: I use 2.7.11 version.I deleted all tables, and past your code, but after executing commands, nothing was change

Answer (score 0):

In your product entity add following code and then run those commands for db and cache, then you will see this column in your table. (You cannot create mapping while creating entity via command so you have create variables for those columns manually.)

```
/**
 * @var categoryId
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer" , nullable = false)
 */
private $categoryId;
```

Comment: this is not the way you create joins in symfony, the `category_id` is created by default when you use `JoinColumn` like he's using `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

Comment: Do you think it is solution of my problem?

Comment: @Vadim.K, I'm sorry but I personally do not consider this as being a solution.

Comment: I tried add this code, but after generate entities I doesn' have column in table and get and set functions...

Comment: php app/console doctrine:schema:validate (run to see your schema has errors or not)